# Flux with repeatWhen never terminates with using onCancel

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

**What I am trying to do with my code**

I want to build an infinite `Flux` that checks for a condition(A feature flag) and then moves on to process the request based on if the condition is true or not. This can lead to two paths:

- Condition is true. Move forward with processing and then `repeat` the `Flux`
- Condition is false. Don't do any processing but `repeat` the `Flux` with `exponentialBackoff` of some duration
- If the downstream processing throws an error then `retry` the `Flux`

To fulfill above requirements, I have the following code.

```
public Flux<String> getData(String request) {
    return Flux.just(request)
               .repeatWhen(Repeat.onlyIf(context -> isEnabled()))
               .repeatWhen(Repeat.onlyIf(context -> !isEnabled())
                                 .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(1L), Duration.ofSeconds(5L)))
               .flatMap(this::process)
               .retry();
               
}
```

**Issue with testing**

Now when I am trying to test this by mocking the `isEnabled` function to return a false value, I am expecting to wait for some time and then expect no elements being returned from the flux.

I have tried testing the above code in 4 ways as follows:

**Without virtual time using thenAwait()**

```
Flux<String> response = getData(sampleRequest);

StepVerifier.create(response)
         .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
         .expectNextCount(0L)
         .thenCancel()
         .verify();
```

**Without virtual time using expectNoEvent()**

```
Flux<String> response = getData(sampleRequest);

StepVerifier.create(response)
         .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
         .thenCancel()
         .verify();
```

**With virtual time using thenAwait()**

```
Flux<String> response = getData(sampleRequest);

StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> response)
         .expectSubscription()
         .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
         .expectNextCount(0L)
         .thenCancel()
         .verify();
```

**With virtual time using expectNoEvent()**

```
Flux<String> response = getData(sampleRequest);

StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> response)
         .expectSubscription()
         .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
         .thenCancel()
         .verify();
```

All the above tests end up running indefinitely without terminating. I wanted to understand what am I missing in the scenario when `isEnabled` is false. I understand the re-subscription happens in the background once it encounters a false value for the condition but why doesn't `StepVerifier` cancels the ongoing `Flux`.

It will be really helpful if someone can point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat, the default configuration could be an unlimited amount of attempts (Long.MAX_VALUE) with a global timeout(Duration).

use repeatMax(3)  that repeats at most 3 times

```
 .repeatWhen(Repeat.onlyIf(context -> !isEnabled())
  .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(1L),Duration.ofSeconds(9L)).repeatMax(3))
```

Comment: But I want to repeat it indefinitely with a backoff. I don't want to cancel the flux after 3 repeat attempts. I want to understand why is the `Flux` not getting cancelled using the `thenCancel`

Comment: StepVerifier - Scenario:
DEBUG reactor.test.StepVerifier -  <expectSubscription>
DEBUG reactor.test.StepVerifier -  <thenAwait>
DEBUG reactor.test.StepVerifier -  <expectNextCount(1)>
DEBUG reactor.test.StepVerifier -  <assertNext>
DEBUG reactor.test.StepVerifier -  <thenCancel>
DEBUG reactor.retry.DefaultRepeat - Stopping repeats since predicate returned false, retry context: iteration=1 repeatCompanionValue=1 backoff={0ms}
DEBUG reactor.retry.DefaultRepeat - Scheduling repeat attempt, retry context: iteration=1 repeatCompanionValue=1 backoff={1000ms/9000ms}

Comment: I am seeing the thenCancel too in log.

Comment: StepVerifier.create(response).expectSubscription().thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(5L))
                .expectNextCount(1L)
                .assertNext(System.out::println)
                .thenCancel().log()
                .verify();

Comment: Yes. I can verify that the cancel is invoked. My best guess is that the repeat happens in background thread which stepverifier cannot get hold due to which it is unable to cancel the running flux.